# laravel: How to store values in array, from collection using each method

Tags: php, laravel

```
 $all_display = array();
 $ad_all->each(function($ad){
     $all_display[] =array('num'=>$ad->num);
 });
 print_r($all_display);
```

alternative

```
 $all_display = array();
 $ad_all->each(function($ad) use ($all_display){
     $all_display[] =array('num'=>$ad->num);
 });
 print_r($all_display);
```

`$ad_all` has four rows, but when I print `$all_display`, it doesn't display anything.

Comment: did you try var_dump, instead of print?

Comment: @Eric bro var_dump also prints nothing

Answer (score 3):

Laravel has envisioned this with a [Collection::only](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-only) method.

```
var_dump($ad_all->only('num')->toArray());
```

Answer (score -1):

Changing each to foreach works

```
 $all_display = array(); 
 foreach($ad_all as $ad){
     $all_display[] =array('num'=>$ad->num);
 }
```

But I don't know why each doesn't work..

Comment: I believe that's beacause with `each` you have to return a value each iteration.